# Button's id undefinded, creating a gameboard in Js

Tags: javascript, css, button, grid, undefined

I am new to JavaScript and need some help.

I am creating a sudoku gameboard using multiple buttons. I want to draw/color the border of every third line and every third column, to evidentiate those 3x3 boxes. The problem is when I try to get each button's ID it says 'undefined' and I can't do what I intended.

What am I doing wrong? Or how should I color those lines that I am talking about?

```js
function createButtons() {
  var gameboard = document.getElementById("gameboard");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.id = i + "." + j;
      button.innerHTML = "cell " + i + "-" + j;
      gameboard.appendChild(button);
    }
  }
}

function drawLines() {
  var button = document.getElementsByName("button");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 81; i++) {
    if (button.id == 3 + "." + i || button.id == 6 + "." + i) {
      button.style.border.bottom = "5px solid red"; //I don't know if this is correct
    }
    if (button.id == i + "." + 3 || button.id == i + "." + 6) {
      button.style.border = "5px";
      button.style.border.right = "solid yellow";
    }
  }
}

createButtons();
drawLines();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #0f4c5c;
}

h1,
h5 {
  color: white;
}

.sudoku #gameboard {
  width: 40vmin;
  height: 40vmin;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  gap: 0;
}

.sudoku button {
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="row mx-auto my-3" id="title">
          Sudoku
        </h1>
        <div class="row my-2 container sudoku">
          <div class="gameboard" id="gameboard"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `drawLines()` function is the root of the problem here.

As stated in my commend, `getElementsByName` will return undefined in this instance as there is no element on the DOM with a name attribute.

A different approach you could take would be to give every button a class name and target them all using `getElementsByClassName`, which you can then loop through, possibly using a `map` or `forEach`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

In order to get every third element in the array, consider using the modulus operator (%).

Please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder for more information on usage of modulus.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I realized I could just change the border color (draw lines) at the same time as I was adding the buttons (in createButtons), so I got rid of drawLines() and solved my problem.